# How to avoid copying references assemblies and be able to run unit tests

Tags: c#, build, continuous-integration, teamcity

I am using TeamCity to build a .NET product.

I'd like to take all of the solution(s) outputs and gather them under a single folder.

In order to do so, i'd like to set CopyLocal to false for all projects, so that when i copy **/*.dll it will not copy redundant files.

We have a big .sln file with projects, most of them are referencing our API assembly, and some are inter-referencing other projects from the solution.

While this is OK for debugging, i'd like to be able to pickup ONLY each project's output and copy it to some folder after build succeeds, without copying the referenced files into that folder as well.

At the same time, when dropping the referenced files from being copied, running unit tests doesn't work on the build server, since some of them require references assemblies.

I can't seem to get my head around it to fix this issue, without perhaps running the build twice (one for running tests, the other for actually getting a "clean" set of folders to copy from).

Any suggestions for managing such a build ?

Comment: What are the "redundant files" which you don't want to copy? It sounds like they're not redundant at all. I would suggest using CopyLocal=true and getting it working that way...

Comment: Copying reference assemblies is essential to get debugging and unit tests going.  The CLR only looks in a select few locations for assemblies, a DLL Hell counter-measure.  Don't disable it.  Or create your own DLL Hell by implementing an event handler for AppDomain.AssemblyResolve.

Comment: @jonskeet i have updated my question. These files are redundant from the viewpoint of storing them as the project's output. They are not needed as part of each project's output, therefore i would like to not include them.

Comment: @liortal: What actual harm are the extra files doing? Can't you just pick the files you want when you come to package up the assemblies?

Comment: Since we're trying to enforce an organized directory structure of our app. We have a solution that builds 40 DLLs. I want to simply pick each project's output and copy it elsewhere. It would be very hard to copy *.dll since it will pick up files that are not needed. I would have no way to determine which is the project output and which is not later on.

Comment: @HansPassant this whole discussion is around a build server, not for actual debugging/testing of our code on developer machines.

Comment: How are we supposed to interpret "run unit tests" in the question title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your actually using to run your builds. Are you using a build script like msbuild or nant? or using the built in TeamCity build steps?

If you're using MsBuild then you can get the path of all compiled assemblies using the following:

```
<MSBuild Projects="@(Solutions)" Targets="Rebuild">
  <Output ItemName="Outputs" TaskParameter="TargetOutputs"/>
</MSBuild>
```

***Outputs*** will now contains the full path to each assembly. This means that you can now add an extra step to copy these files elsewhere for storage, or you can delete all other unwanted files (e.g clean) after you have run your unit tests e.g.

```
<CreateItem Include="$(BuildOutputDir)\**\*.*" Exclude="@(Outputs)">
  <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="FilesToClean"/>
</CreateItem>

<Delete Files="@(FilesToClean)" />
```

I can't test the above as I'm not at my dev machine but hope that helps

Comment: Right now i am using the built in MSBuild runner, supplying it with a .sln file. I thought about this option, this means i will now write a build script in MSBuild (something i've wanted to do anyway in some time). Thanks, this should work :)